# Request.get timeout

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, error-handling, python-requests

i wanted with the help of Requests function get the HTML of a site.

my Code:

```
import Requests
res = Requests.get('https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-laserjet-pro-m404n?jumpid=ma_weekly-deals_product-tile_printers_3_w1a52a_hp-laserjet-pro-m404')

print(res.text)
```

The Code gets stuck at res. If you were to replace the http with : 
'http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=GTX&bop=And&Page=1&PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH' - everything works just fine.

**How can i** save the html of any given page into a variable?

Comment: Your question title and your question body are not consistent. You are saying `request.get` timeout in the title but your question just say the "code stuck". And in the end of your question, you then ask something else. Better to edit your question so that others can help you better. And if there is any error, you should paste the error message as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are dealing with `HP` website which is definitely using modern web technology.

The issue here that you are making the `request` without a valid `User-Agent` which will cause the `firewall` of the `website` to block the `request` and list it as a `bot`

That's why you are getting error# `10060` [Details](https://help.globalscape.com/help/archive/cuteftp6/socket_error_=__10060.htm)

Here you can make a valid `request` and store `HTML` source as `variable`

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'}

r = requests.get(
    "https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-laserjet-pro-m404n?jumpid=ma_weekly-deals_product-tile_printers_3_w1a52a_hp-laserjet-pro-m404", headers=headers)

print(r)

html = r.text # now it's stored
```

Answer (score 0):

This site looks like it implements some basic anti-scraping methods. If a request works in the browser but not in your code, you just need to adapt the request, headers, cookies, etc until it more closely match what the browser does. Thankfully this one is easy to work with. Ensure you provide a user agent :)

```
res = requests.get('https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-laserjet-pro-m404n?jumpid=ma_weekly-deals_product-tile_printers_3_w1a52a_hp-laserjet-pro-m404',
               headers={'user-agent':'my app'})
```